# How to center header texts on TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, header, tabitem

I'm trying to get my WPF TabItems to center their header texts. But no matter which combinations of HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment (center or stretch) I set on the ContentPresenter and its containing Border, the text always appears aligned to the left, rather than centered. I also don't see a Property on TabItems that I could use to set this directly on the tab items themselves (as it turns out, HorizontalAlignment on a TabItem does something completely different).

My code right now is this:

```
<Grid TextElement.Foreground="White" TextElement.FontSize="17" TextElement.FontFamily="Times New Roman" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
   <Border Name="TabBorder" BorderThickness="8 8 8 0"  CornerRadius="12 12 0 0"  
           Background="{StaticResource bandBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
   <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ContentSource="Header" Height="24" Width="100" />
   </Border>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the ContentPresenter in a Label with the HorizontalAlignment property set to Strecth and the HorizontalContentAlignment set to Center,
Check out [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29c3da55-a17b-4af6-9054-f2741da09b73/wpf-how-to-make-tabitem-header-text-show-in-center-of-tab-header-control-and-whole-header-is?forum=wpf):

```
<Grid x:Name="gridTabItem">
  <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" CornerRadius="7,7,0,0" BorderThickness="0" >
    <Label  x:Name="label" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
      <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,2,10,2"
                 RecognizesAccessKey="True">
      </ContentPresenter>
    </Label>

  </Border>
  <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Margin="0,41, 0,0" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=gridTabItem}" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{x:Null}"/>
  <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="0,43,0,0" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=gridTabItem}" Fill="#FFEEEEEE"/>
  <Rectangle x:Name="glow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=gridTabItem}" Fill="{x:Null}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I add the label, set its HorizontalAlignment to Stretch and its HorizontalContentAlignment to Center, and then set the contentPresenter's HorizontalAlignment to center, then the texts *still* get aligned to the left. However, if I copy/paste your code into my code instead of my own code, then the headers *are* centered! So this code is probably correct, though I still have to figure out why my own code doesn't work when I adopt the same structure and settings. Will probably accept this answer later...

Comment: Actually, could it have to do with the fact that I'm setting a Width on my ContentPresenter? (Not shown in the code above, as I had removed what I thought was irrelevant.) When I remove the Width, the text may be centered - but it's difficult to see because the tab items become so narrow that the text just fits inside (i.e. tabitem width becomes dependent on the space occupied by the text). And that's not what I want anyway, I'd like all tabs to have equal widths irrespective of text length.

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly when I simply set the Width on the TabItem rather than on the ContentPresenter. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old and there is already accepted answer but I think my answer could help someone.

My problem was that I needed to spread TabItem headers evenly (each TabItem header has the same width) and text inside header needed to be centered. So this is how I have achieved this:

TabControl.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FMEA.Resources.Styles"
                xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:FMEA.Converters"
                xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro">

<Style x:Key="Custom_TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Width">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding>
                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Converters:TabSizeConverter />
                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}" Path="ActualWidth" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="tabItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="content"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border x:Name="border">
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                       FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

where TabSizeConverter is this:

```
class TabSizeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TabControl tabCtrl = values[0] as TabControl;
        double width = tabCtrl.ActualWidth / tabCtrl.Items.Count;
        return width <= 1 ? 0 : width - 1;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
<TabItem Header="MyHeader" Style="{StaticResource Custom_TabItem}">
```